# How to generate assetId names in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to export some images to my assets inventory in Google Earth Engine. To do this I want to generate `assetId`s automatically so the whole exporting operation will fit in a for loop eventually. (yes I know for loops are client-side constructs, but so is `Export.Image.toAsset()`, as far as I understood)

When I try to parse a generated `assetId` to `Export.Image.toAsset()`, the result in the task dialogue is not a string-type however. It actually looks like this:

[image]

How do I correctly parse `assetId` to `Export.Image.toAsset()`?

Here is my example code:

```
// get area of interest 
var andorra = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0")
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', "Andorra"));

// specify dates of interest
var StartDate = '2020-03-18';
var EndDate = '2020-03-31';

// Filter the Landsat 8 collection by date range and area of interest
var imcol = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
    .filterDate(StartDate, EndDate).filterBounds(andorra)
    .sort("system:time_start"); 

// get an image to export
var exportImage = imcol.first();

//  get the date of the image 
var date = ee.String(exportImage.get('DATE_ACQUIRED')); 

// generate an assetID 
var outputName = ee.String('Andorra_LS8_').cat(date); 

// export image 
Export.image.toAsset({
  image: exportImage,
  description: outputName,
  assetId: outputName,
  scale: 30,
  region: andorra,
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the details from outPutname to the client-side:

```
// generate an assetID 
var outputName = ee.String('Andorra_LS8_').cat(date).getInfo();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that solved the problem indeed. By the way: don't you mean that `.getInfo()` brings the contents from the server-side to the client-side?

Comment: Typ0 there, thanks I fixed it!